# Mongodb $group and $avg several fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the daily, weekly and monthly average of entries in a collection in a given timespan.
Here is the query i'm using so far.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "date":{
            $gte:ISODate('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
            $lte:ISODate('2017-12-31T23:59:59.000Z')
          }
    }
},

{
    $project : { 
        "_id":0,
        "day": { $dayOfYear: "$date" }, //returns number between 1 and 366
        "week": { $week: "$date" }, //number between 0 and 53
        "month": { $month: "$date" } //number between 1 and 12
    }
},

{
    $group : {
        "_id":"$month", //change this to $day or $week when needed
        "total":{$sum : 1}
    }
},

{
    $group : {
        "_id":null,
        "total":{$avg : "$total"}
    }
}
])
```

Then i get something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "total" : 4793758.66666666667
}
```

It works, but i can need to change the first $group _id to $day or $week in order to get the results. So i actually run this query three times in order to generate a single report.

Is it possible to get the daily, weekly and monthly average average in a single query?

Comment: Could you please post some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$facet`. Add the below `$facet` stage after `$match` instead of other stages.

Something like

```
{
  "$facet":{
    "day":[
      {"$group":{"_id":{"$dayOfYear":"$date"},"total":{"$sum":1}}}
    ],
    "week":[
      {"$group":{"_id":{"$week":"$date"},"total":{"$sum":1}}}
    ],
    "month":[
      {"$group":{"_id":{"$month":"$date"},"total":{"$sum":1}}}
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$project":{
     "totalDay":{"$avg":"$day.total"},
     "totalWeek":{"$avg":"$week.total"},
     "totalMonth":{"$avg":"$month.total"}
  }
}
```

Comment: The respective second `$group` stages can be extracted from the `$facet` stage and turned into a simple `$project` with three fields (each projecting the on `$avg` of either `$day.total`, `$week.total` or `$month.total`) at the end which would appear a little nicer to me.

Comment: Kind of like this: `$project: { totalDay: { $avg: "$day.total" }, totalWeek: { $avg: "$week.total" }, totalMonth: { $avg: "$month.total" } }`

Comment: @dnickless Makes sense. Thank you.